# Would my app need to be PCI compliant in this case?

Tags: android, pci-compliance

I am using USAePay as the processing gateway and they have a library to send the cardholder's information such as the PAN, EXP date, CVV2 to their servers for payment.

To use this library I would have to implement a user interface consisting of textfields to have the user enter in their data and a submit button to send the data.

In this scenario would my app need to be PCI compliant?

Comment: That is a question for your attorney, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

no you don't need your app to be PCI complaint. The gateway and their library is already PCI complaint.